# Is there a Linux tool to scan Dockerfile (not image) for violations of the Dockerfile best practices?

Tags: docker, podman

I would like to add Dockerfile scanning to our PR pipeline.

Googling for it only comes up with either image scanning or docker scout, which does not seem to be available for podman, which we use on our Linux boxes.

So is Dockerfile scanning something people do at all or is it only the image scanning, which we can do with trivy, for example? And if Dockerfile scanning makes sense - how do you do it on Linux (with podman, without docker)?